# Стоит ли создать дополнительный компонент или можно оставить так?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, компоненты

На сайте есть 2 товара в виде карточки. Они идентичны лишь отличаются контентом. 
У 1-ой карточки изображения приходят с сервера, а у 2-ой оно всегда статичное и + там текст. 
Сейчас код компонента карточки с картинкой выглядит так:

```
const CardHeader = ({img, title}) {
  return (
    <div className={img ? `card__photo` : `card__photo--bg`}>
      {img ? (
        <img src={img} alt="" className="card__photo__img" />
      ) : (
        <p className="card__photo__title">{title}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

И у меня возник вопрос стоит ли делать так и такие проверки, если в 1-ом случае title приходит undefined, в 2-ом случае приходит уже img undefined и как то уже компонент не универсальный получается. Может мне стоит для каждой карточки товара создать отдельный компонент header например: ProductFoodHeader и выводить то что реально приходит без всяких проверок?

Comment: а если тебе придет и img и title или не придет ничего? Что должно вывестись?

Comment: @Grundy Если придут оба, то по сути выведется контент для 1-ой карточки, тут уже title никак не будет взаимодействован. Прийти ничего никак не может т.к я проверяю на верхнем уровне содержимое информаций. Если пусто я даже контент рендерить не буду.

Comment: @Grundy Я этот компонент использую в двух разных умных компонентах. В одном я передаю img, в другом title. И решил спросить более опытных разработчиков, как мне поступить в плане архитектуры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае лучше разделить на два компонента, так как они между собой никак не связаны.

```
const CardHeader = ({img}) {
  return (
    <div className={`card__photo`}>
        <img src={img} alt="" className="card__photo__img" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const CardHeader = ({title}) {
  return (
    <div className={`card__photo--bg`}>
        <p className="card__photo__title">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Теперь сами компоненты стали проще, в них убрались ненужные условия и поведение определяется всего одним условием вверху, где выбирается какой из компонентов будет использоваться